# Storing Large amount of file paths in DB

Tags: database, filepath, hierarchical-data

I need some approach for the most efficient way to store file (and folder) paths in DB (near a million records), such that I can search for there names.

Saving the full path is obviously wrong, because a lot of repetition will occur, for example:

```
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System
C:\Windows\System\Notepad.exe
```

For this, I built a simple hierarchical DB, with just three fields:

```
ID           Name           Parent
0                C:                null
1            Windows            0
2             System             1
3          Notepad.exe        2
```

And I am recovering item's path by using a "recursive with" statement.

The performance is totally satisfactory, however, I am not satisfied with DB size, using SQLite gives you expected DB size (if you will calculate it size depending on average string length in "Name" column), but I been shocked when I compared it to DB size of the famous file searching utility "Everything", having same number of records (as "everything" reports), there DB is 3-4 times smaller!

Because it is potentially possible to have up to 10 million records in future, I am worried that there should be a more efficient way for storage, any ideas?

P.S
This is not about which DB vendor to use, or that even with 10 mil. rec. DB is of 500Mb size still ok, but a conceptual question, if there is more efficient way.

Comment: The first question to ask is, if a relational approach is the proper way to solve your problem. If you must go relational, your database table design is the essential key to performance. On any relational database, the tradeoff is "give more space, get more speed"; the means stuff like indexes etc which can tune your queries are bought by the cost of disk space. An finally, if you are using varchar type columns, the used space should be quite minimal. the tradeoff on varchar is, that the rows inside of the table pages are not fix sized any more.

Comment: Well, I cann't really see how for example saving full path will give me better performance, as there will be need to search greater amount of strings, also as I said I am happy with performance, so sacrificing it little bit is ok if I can reduce space, but my question is how? I can't see how I can reduce space more at all! And I am already using varchar.

Comment: A full path enables you to find a path through an index on the path column instead of walking through the data. This is really fast; I am not sure in how far SQLLite supports full text indexes, but if yes, full text search will enable you to have full indexed wildcard searches. But you are correct, thats all performance gain which you currently don't need. Organization of data is massively beeing influenced by the database vendor since its part of the table drivers of the db. Maybe this helps you in order to find a way to save space : http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html

Comment: 2nd : you could store the data as a structured storage (binary file) and search it by hand. this enables you to have the uttermost control over the data and it's sizing, but the tradeoff is not having a versatile database query language like sql.

Comment: Yes I thought amount binary thing, but the actual trade of is not Sql, but that I will need to reconvert it row by row to string for searching, this is very inefficient, or to store all days in memory, what is also not option, I will check your link, maybe I will find something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimising Sqlite db size when indexing 2M files with long paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57931005/minimising-sqlite-db-size-when-indexing-2m-files-with-long-paths)