# Minimising Sqlite db size when indexing 2M files with long paths

Tags: sqlite

I need to index around 2 million files on each of several linux systems and I am worried the naive way to do this might create an unnecessarily large data file because of the longish path names (IE the text of an average path, perhaps /home/user/Android/gradle/blah/blah/blah/filename, times 2 million).

Assuming I put the filename in a column of its own and the path in a different column, with identical text (ie the full path) which is repeated frequently in a table, will Sqlite automatically store the full text once and just use a pointer to it in each row? If not is there a way I can instruct it to do this behind the scenes without having to code it? To code it will be a PITA (quite rusty with sql at the mo) and if I put the text in a separate table I'm wondering if it will slow it all down at run time too.

Will probably use perl for this and the intention is to find replicated data across machines with slow interconnections, so index files, make hashes of all files, transfer db files and test against other machines.

TIA, Pete

Comment: There is no automatic consolidation of data.  It will store data redundantly as you specify the schema.

Comment: Look into [windowing functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) and recursive CTE (Common Table Expressions) using the [WITH statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html).  Those could facilitate storing full paths as hierarchical rows of folder.  That would resolve storing redundant paths.  Such hierarchical data are not possible (or very difficult) using standard SQL and relational tables.  Exact implementations are perhaps too broad and/or would generate opinionated answers here on SO, but this should be a start to store such data efficiently using sqlite.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I found it too hard to get my head round the CTEs so decided to roll the thing myself. Still working on it but I have my head around what I need to do now. Thanks for your advise, pointed me in the direction I needed to prevent pointless work!

Comment: FYI: This [old unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839642/storing-large-amount-of-file-paths-in-db) essentially asks the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic schema and corresponding query for storing file paths.  Similar queries could be crafted to, e.g., get all files for a particular folder, or get a relative path of a file.  Other meta data can be added to either table or to an auxiliary table.  I am not claiming efficiency for any particular purpose other than this schema will avoid storing redundant path strings.

First the schema and sample data.  Notice the recursive foreign-key relationship on the `folders` table, referring to itself:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS files;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS folders;

CREATE temp TABLE folders (
       id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
       parent_id INTEGER,
       name NOT NULL,
       --! UNIQUE(parent_id, name), --* Changed to unique index definition
       FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES folders (id)
);
--* Multiple identical null values were allowed with a unique constraint defined on the table.
--* Instead define a unique index that explicitly converts null values to an effective id value
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX folders_unique_root ON folders
       (coalesce(parent_id, -1), name);

CREATE temp TABLE files (
       id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
       folder_id INTEGER,
       name NOT NULL,
       UNIQUE(folder_id, name),
       FOREIGN KEY (folder_id) REFERENCES folders (id)
);

INSERT INTO folders
       (id, parent_id, name)
VALUES
       --* Although id is AUTOINCREMENT, explicitly assign here to make hierarchical relationships obvious
       (1, null, 'home'),
       (2,    1, 'dev'),
       (3,    2, 'SO'),
       (4,    1, 'docs'),
       (5,    1, 'sys');

INSERT INTO files
       (folder_id, name)
VALUES
       (1, 'readme.txt'),
       (3, 'recursive.sql'),
       (3, 'foobar'),
       (4, 'homework.txt');

COMMIT;
```

Now a query for recovering full paths of the files.  I'll add a few comments, but to understand each detail I defer to the official docs for the [WITH statement](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) and [Window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
     file_path_levels AS (
         --* Prime the recursion with file rows
         SELECT id AS file_id,
                1 AS level,
                folder_id,
                name
         FROM files
         --WHERE name == 'foobar' --For selecting particular file
         UNION ALL
         --* Continue recursion by joining to next folder in relationship
         SELECT file_id,
                level + 1,
                folders.parent_id,
                folders.name
         FROM file_path_levels  --* Refer to own name to cause recursion
              LEFT JOIN folders --* Get row of parent folder
                   ON file_path_levels.folder_id = folders.id
         WHERE folders.id is not null --Necessary condition to terminate recursion
     ),
     file_path_steps AS (
         --* Now concatenate folders into path string
         SELECT file_id,
                level,
                '/' || group_concat(name, '/') 
                    OVER (PARTITION BY file_id 
                          ORDER BY level DESC)
                    AS full_path
         FROM file_path_levels
     )
SELECT file_id, full_path
FROM file_path_steps
WHERE level == 1;
```

This produces

```
file_id   full_path
1         /home/readme.txt
2         /home/dev/SO/recursive.sql
3         /home/dev/SO/foobar
4         /home/docs/homework.txt
```

It's possible to inspect details of intermediate results by replacing the final query with something to retrieve rows from the other named CTE queries, optionally excluding WHERE conditions to see what each step produces.  This will help in learning what each part does.  For example, try this after the WITH clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM file_path_levels
ORDER BY file_id, level;
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that - I had to put this down for a while but recently coming back to it, I've been hoping I wouldn't need to do [my main task] this way but it still looks like there is no alternative. So I will likely use this code as my starting point (suppose at least it will refresh me on sql).